# Creating a file(html/json/xml) on ubuntu server uding nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I'm using nodejs and I need to create a file on ubuntu server(using ip, username and path). Could anyone suggest any method to do this?

Comment: You want to create file on remote server? or your nodejs server is on the same ubuntu server?

Comment: both. it should be able to create files on the local and remote server.

Comment: google it for **sshpass**

Comment: I suggest checking your spelling next time.